# Oracle driver com.oracle.jdbc or com.oracle.weblogic?

Tags: oracle, maven, nexus

I configured my Nexus to proxy maven.oracle.com and I am able to browse the index, so I know it worked. Oracle's documentation from this year (https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/oracle_maven_repository_instructions_for) gives this as the dependency for their driver:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
 <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
 <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But I cannot find it and Maven can't resolve it. I do find a jar ojdbc7 under a different GAV in their maven repo though:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
   <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>        
</dependency>
```

Have I configured it wrong? Or is their doc wrong?

[image]

Comment: Same problem here. I guess the documentation is wrong. The index hasn't been updated since January 2015 (https://maven.oracle.com/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties)...